# How to access particular Observable items?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a function:

```
getCategories(): Observable<any>
        {
         return this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}})
        };
```

where this.category.find return type is `Observable<T[]>`.

I call getCategories() with:

```
const source = this.categoryService.getCategories();
const example = source.map(Categ=> Categ.id);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

and Categ.id is **undefined**

If I run:

```
const source = this.categoryService.getCategories();
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

directly, the output is :
[image]

I think I have a type problem somewhere but cannot figure it out.

Any idea ?

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this.category.find returns an Observable?

Comment: Yes is does as **console.log(source instanceof Observable);** is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed with the types. You should avoid using "any" when possible because then you loose advantage of type validation.

From the log it is visible that the `source` contains an array but your `source.map(Categ=> Categ.id)` treats it as single objects.

It would be better to define `Categ` interface, e.g.:

```
interface Categ {
    id: string;
    categoryName: string;
    clientId: string;
}
```

Then use it for service method:

```
getCategories(): Observable<Categ[]> {
     return this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}})
};
```

so later compiler can help you to spot the problem and fix the code:

```
const source = this.categoryService.getCategories();
const example = source.map(categ => categ.map(c => c.id));
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact I resolved it with: **const example = source.map((categories) => categories.map((category) => {return category.id}));**

Answer (score 1):

As an array of categories is returned by the `getCategories()` and not just a single category as is evidenced by your subscribe's console log.

You could try something like:

```
const example = source.map((categories) => categories.map((category) => {return category.id}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is writing an interface something "too much"?
My .find() method is coming from a SDK and returning `Observable<T[]>`. Also, I am in a service because I would like to get data from the back-end and call this service from a component. I have no idea if this service has a use as it is about only this **getCategories()** method.
To simplify, I already have a method that gives me categories. I just created a new one to set it in the service.
So is creating an interface too much? What do you think?